# List lotto rows

Tags: python

The task is to make a list of every lotto row if in a lotto, seven numbers are chosen from 39 numbers. Is there more elegant way to do this than my solution:

```
rows = []
for a in range(1,40):
    for b in range(a+1,40):
        for c in range(b+1,40):
            for d in range(c+1,40):
                for e in range(d+1,40):
                    for f in range(e+1,40):
                        for g in range(f+1,40):
                           rows.append([a,b,c,d,e,f,g])
```

Comment: Regardless of the style of code, you will wait quite a lot its execution :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools

rows = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 40), 7))
```

If you want to know how to implement this without using a built-in, just read the sample implementation of `itertools.combinations` in the document.

Comment: I'd go even further and use a `set` instead of a `list` just to be sure you have unique elements.

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex. The returned elements are guaranteed to be unique as long as the iterable (`range(1, 40)` here) itself has no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Code with this much indentation is never elegant, and it is very hard to maintain.

There is a programming principle called the [Don't Repeat Yourself Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) sometimes referred to as DRY code. If you find yourself repeating the same code multiple times it is better to encapsulate it in a function. If it is possible to loop through the code that can reduce repetition as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do the DRY thing like that here. Rather sounds like you copied&pasted that paragraph from somewhere where that made more sense.